# Use Boost C++ in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, boost, xcode6

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_register (std::type_info const&)", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::pair<long long   const, long long> >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::map<long long,  long long, std::__1::less<long long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> > > >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
 "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_unregister()", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> >::~extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::map<long long, long long, std::__1::less<long long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> > > >::~extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
 "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::extended_type_info_typeid_0(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::map<long long, long long, std::__1::less<long long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> > > >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
 "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::~extended_type_info_typeid_0()", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> >::~extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
  boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::map<long long,  long long, std::__1::less<long long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> > > >::~extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<std::__1::map<long long, long long, std::__1::less<long long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<long long const, long long> > > >::extended_type_info_typeid() in TestC.o
```

I use Boost C++ library for my objective-c project. I followed this instruction to add boost to Xcode:
http://freddy.cellcore.org/post/79587278354/boost-c-libraries-on-osx-xcode-5
After adding boost.framework, I can include the headers without error.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
```

But when I add some lines of code as below, press build, it shows errors above.

```
std::map<int64_t, int64_t> foo;
boost::filesystem::path myFile = boost::filesystem::current_path() / "myfile.dat";

if (filesystem::exists(myFile))
{
    filesystem::ifstream ifs(myFile/*.native()*/);
    archive::text_iarchive ta(ifs);

    ta >> foo; // foo is empty until now, it's fed by myFile

    std::cout << "Read " << foo.size() << " entries from " << myFile << "\n";
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) foo[i] = 10;
    filesystem::ofstream ofs(myFile/*.native()*/);
    archive::text_oarchive ta(ofs);

    ta << foo; // foo is empty until now, it's fed by myFile
    std::cout << "Wrote " << foo.size() << " random entries to " << myFile << "\n";
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't access that Github page anymore but I'm guessing you only have the x86 version, not the x64 version.

[Try this...](https://gist.github.com/rsobik/7513324)

From the script:

```
# To configure the script, define:
#    BOOST_LIBS:        which libraries to build
#    IPHONE_SDKVERSION: iPhone SDK version (e.g. 5.1)
#
# Then go get the source tar.bz of the boost you want to build, shove it in the
# same directory as this script, and run "./boost.sh".
```

Or you could try this version instead? It's precompiled...
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you provided is exactly the one I added in the question.

Comment: What did you set BOOST_LIBS to when you built it? And which source tar.bz?

Comment: I just keep the shell script when building framework, it downloads 1.56.0

Comment: I edited my answer - there is a pre-compiled 64 bit version for iOS

Comment: Thank you, but I can not make it work, even precompiled version. Did you successfully try it ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm missing to put serialization in BOOST_LIBS